# Getting token from an asp.net web api in iOS / swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am a `.net` developer but very new to `iOS` and `swift` development, just need help with consuming Web API using `Swift2`

The `Asp.net` Web API has been built with `OAuth2` authentication, published to my Azure VM server with SSL certificate installed. The API site itself works properly, tested through Postman

However I got stuck when started writing first few lines of code in Swift trying to get Authentication token. After reading some online tutorials I decided to engage `Alamofire`, and produced below codes snippet:

```
func GetToken() {

    let params = [
        "grant_type" : "password",
        "username" : "123456@qq.com",
        "password" : "averygoodpassword"
    ]

    let headers = [
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

    request(.POST, "https://api.example.com/token",
        parameters: params,
        headers: headers,
        encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in

            print (request)
            print (response?.description)
            print (result)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

            case .Failure(let data, let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

                if let data = data {
                    print("Response data: \(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)")
                }
            }

    }

}
```

It ends up with below output in `Xcode` which didn't seem to be OK. The `error = unsupported_grant_type` told me that the request were sent to server but the parameters were not sent with request properly. I really cannot figure out the reason and solution, had been digging on Internet for a few days but still feeling desperate with it. Can anyone help please? Even if someone can provide a pure swift solution without any 3rd party library will be greatly helpful. Thanks!

**Xcode output:**

> Optional( { URL: https://api.example.com/token })
>       Optional(" { URL: https://api.example.com/token } { status code: 400, headers {\n    \"Access-Control-Allow-Headers\" = \"Content-Type\";\n    \"Access-Control-Allow-Methods\" = \"GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS\";\n    \"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\" = \"*\";\n    \"Cache-Control\" = \"no-cache\";\n    \"Content-Length\" = 34;\n    \"Content-Type\" = \"application/json;charset=UTF-8\";\n    Date = \"Fri, 30 Sep 2016 10:30:31 GMT\";\n    Expires = \"-1\";\n    Pragma = \"no-cache\";\n    Server = \"Microsoft-IIS/8.5\";\n    \"X-Powered-By\" = \"ASP.NET\";\n} }")
>       SUCCESS
>       Success with JSON: {
>           error = "unsupported_grant_type";
>       }

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem trying to POST to MailGun for some automated emails I was implementing in an app.

I was able to get this working properly with a large HTTP response. I put the full path into Keys.plist so that I can upload my code to github and broke out some of the arguments into variables so I can have them programmatically set later down the road.

```
// Email the FBO with desired information
// Parse our Keys.plist so we can use our path
var keys: NSDictionary?

if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Keys", ofType: "plist") {
    keys = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}

if let dict = keys {
    // variablize our https path with API key, recipient and message text
    let mailgunAPIPath = dict["mailgunAPIPath"] as? String
    let emailRecipient = "bar@foo.com"
    let emailMessage = "Testing%20email%20sender%20variables"

    // Create a session and fill it with our request
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: mailgunAPIPath! + "from=FBOGo%20Reservation%20%3Cscheduler@<my domain>.com%3E&to=reservations@<my domain>.com&to=\(emailRecipient)&subject=A%20New%20Reservation%21&text=\(emailMessage)")!)

    // POST and report back with any errors and response codes
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }

        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.URL!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

The Mailgun Path is in Keys.plist as a string called mailgunAPIPath with the value:

```
https://API:key-<my key>@api.mailgun.net/v3/<my domain>.com/messages?
```

I'm slightly opposed to using 3rd party libraries, especially for small things like a http POST and this seems like a much more maintainable solution to me. Anyways, hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: The question relates to using Alamofire with OAuth2.  Answer should provide an example using Alamofire, rather than saying "opposed to using 3rd party libraries"